# What does JScript object expected mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [instafeedjs](http://instafeedjs.com/) to display Instagram images on my website, it works in modern browsers but *Internet Explorer 8* I see a Javascript error. It says

```
JScript object expected
instafeed.min.js Line 2
Code 0 Char:3392
URI (outputs the correct absolute link to the script)
```

I've put the `instafeed.min.js` script right at the bottom of the page in the source and it's placed after `jquery-1.11.1.min.js` both paths to the scripts are correct.

I don't understand the error message, can anyone explain it?

Comment: JScript is Microsoft's dialect of the ECMAScript standard that is used in Microsoft's Internet Explorer. JScript is implemented as an Active Scripting engine. JScript is Microsoft's version of JavaScript.

Comment: I see, do you know what 'object expected' means? I assume it means it's looking for an ID or something, but the error message doesn't appear to be very helpful. Thanks for replying!

Comment: Can you post your header from your web page? Or where your insert the js libraries? Also, could you post the code that is causing the error.

Comment: It usually means that you accessed a property on a variable that does not hold an object.